# Xamarin sqLite.SQLiteException: Constraint using two databases

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

basically what im trying to do is save the same data in two DBs, the DBs are exactly the same (only changes the DB name), when i save the data in first DB is fine, when it try to save in the second one it show the error `sqLite.SQLiteException: Constraint` 
here is the code:

```
var order = new Order
            {
                Id = Generator.GenerateKey(),
                OrderNumber = OrderN,
                OrderDate = DateTimeHelpers.GetDate(),
                CustomerId = SelectedCustomer.Id,
                TotalPrice = totalPrice,
                Discount = DeductMoney,
                TaxAmount = TaxAmount,
                IsSync = false,
                PayMethod = PayMethod,
                Customer = new Customer
                {
                    Id = SelectedCustomer.Id
                },
                DiscountType = (int)PopupDiscountInfo.DiscountType,
                Creator = StoreSettings?.StoreOwner,
                Notes = Notes
            };
            order.OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();

            var orderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
            foreach (var item in ProductInSaleOrders)
            {
                orderDetails.Add(new OrderDetail
                {
                    Id = Generator.GenerateKey(),
                    ProductId = item.Id,
                    UnitId = item.UnitId,
                    Product = new Product
                    {
                        Id = item.Id
                    },
                    Unit = new Unit
                    {
                        Id = item.UnitId
                    },
                    Price = item.Price,
                    Quantity = item.Quantity
                });
            }

            await _orderService.SaveOrderAsync(order);
            await _orderDetailService.SaveOrderDetailAsync(orderDetails);
            await _orderService.SaveOrderAsyncB(order);
            await _orderDetailService.SaveOrderDetailBAsync(orderDetails);
```

when it reach `await _orderService.SaveOrderAsyncB(order);` the error shows up

OrderService.cs

```
public async Task SaveOrderAsyncB(Order order)
        {
            await _orderRepositoryB.InsertWithChildrenAsync(CryptoEngine.EncryptOrder(order));
        }
```

i been reading about this error but nothing solves my problem

Edit: when i delete the "await" from `await _orderService.SaveOrderAsyncB(order);` it seens to work but no data is been saved to the DB, i checked on the conections and everything is OK, but i keep getting the Constraint error even when the two DB are totally empty.

Comment: are you sure you are using two different connections?  Are you sure there are not any constraints that you are violating on the 2nd db?

Comment: @Jason I'm pretty sure that the second connection works (before I had problems because my application can't find the second one, so if I'm using the connection for the first database, I would never notice that the second db file doesn't exist)

Comment: Does the behavior change if you swap the order of the Save operations?

Comment: Are you sure the DBs are exactly the same? See  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41794114/10539446) about the error message.

Comment: @Jason if i swap the order i have the same problem with the second DB, so is not a problem of saving in the same DB twice, the problem is in the second DB.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT is a copy-paste of the first DB, iva already seen that answer but it doens't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the two tables that i tried to insert (Order and OrderDetail) have relations with other tables like costumer, podruct, etc. 
the solution was saving all the data in both DBs and not only in the first one.